# How to setup a server I can call via modem to access the internet?

Tags: networking, router, internet, dial-up

My parents live in a rural area, just outside of a small town, and have very poor internet service because there's no fibre op connections available where they live.

In town where they run a business, there's great internet service, which they pay for and only use while they're in town.

**Is there some way I can setup a system so they can call their internet in town, and access it via a "fast" modem?**

And if so, how fast could it be, and could that internet be shared throughout their house via wifi?

Points of note:

- They're open to installing a separate phone line, as this is a short distance (local call) to the business.
- I'm open to Mac/PC/Windows/Linux solutions,
- Preferably opensource, but am totally willing to pay if a commercial product makes this work better.
- And I'm reasonably "techie" and can setup hardware/software as required.

Comment: How fast? Well, as fast as a modem can be. So real fcking slow. Also, the telephone bill! Unless they have a phone flatrate (which is still fair use, btw), they’ll have to pay a regular phone call.

Comment: Good point - They'd be willing to install an extra phone line if it'd improve their service/speed at all. I'll add this to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a connection between two point over a phone line is fairly easy; it requires a server computer at the destination which runs an RRAS service. **But your question includes the word "fast"** which practically renders all solutions that I can recommend very expensive.

1. You can purchase a T1 (United States) or E1 (Europe) line between the two points from a phone company. It allows you to have a 1.544 Mbit/s connection between the two locations. I don't remember the price right now but I do remember that the last time I heard it, my head swirled.
2. You can setup a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line) connection between the two points over a phone line but that means you need to purchase a [DSLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line_access_multiplexer) device and sign a contract with the phone company to let you install it in one of their exchange stations. VERY EXPENSIVE.

There are satellite solutions but they are neither cheap nor fast.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So what type of speeds could I expect over a RRAS service without a DSL connection?

Comment: @BradParks Like I said, modem speeds. In case you missed that period of time: 56kbit/s.

Comment: 56 Kbit/s equals 7 kilobytes per second (kB/s)